# odds of selecting in probability

Tags: probability

The odds of selecting a boy's name from the class list in ms.Wolf's class are 5:7. The probability of selecting a boy is?

my work:

since the odds of selecting a boys name is 5:7 you can simply just divide 5 by 7 and you will end up with 0.714
so answer=0.714 (probability of selecting a boy)

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Odds are different from probability.

Comment: yes im aware of that

Comment: the question is asking the probability of selecting a boy

Comment: Do you know what 5:7 means?

Comment: for every 12 names, 5 of them are boys and 7 are not boys, so the probability of getting a boy is less than 50%

Comment: yes @Joe it means that out of 12 possible outcomes, odds are that there will be 5 of one kind of outcome and 7 of another kind of outcome. For every 12, odds are that 5 will be a particular event and 7 will be another event. 5 to 7

Comment: The whole point of this question is to test your reading comprehension and you understanding of the difference between the term "odds" and "probability."  Given a fair six-sided die the *probability* of rolling a six is $\frac{1}{6}$.  The *odds* of having done so on the other hand are $1:5$.  The question is testing your understanding of how to convert from an answer written as odds to an answer written as a probability.

Comment: Given your comment, it sounds like you do indeed understand how to read and explain what odds represent, in this case that for an odds of $5:7$ that $5$ out of $12$ times on average we will see the event occur and the remaining $7$ out of $12$ times on average we will see the event not occur.  All that remains then is to recognize that something occurring $5$ out of every $12$ times on average will have a probability of $\dfrac{5}{12}$.  In general, for odds of $x:y$ this implies a probability of $\frac{x}{x+y}$

Answer (score 3):

Odds vs. Probabilities.

To find the odds we compare the number of combinations that satisfy the proposition to the number of combinations that don't.  $5:7$ suggests a ratio of 5 boys to 7 girls.

To find the probability we count the number of combinations that satisfy the proposition and divide by the total number of combinations. $\frac {5}{5+7} = \frac {5}{12} = 0.41\overline 6$

Comment: "*To find the odds... and divide*"  A colon here does not represent division.  $5:7$ is a different expression than $5\div 7$ or $\frac{5}{7}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I have edited my post to express your concern.  But, going back to my childhood, I have always had trouble with this distinction --  in my mind, ratios are fractions and fractions are ratios....  Nonetheless, the world might not agree with me.